# Python Kafka Client triggering error even though consumer works

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am using the confluent_kafka client package version 0.11.5 and Python 3.6.6 for interacting with Apache Kafka. Getting error when the consumer connection has been polling for several minutes. Still able to consume and handle messages correctly from subscribed topic. Seems to only be getting error/fail on some of the brokers I used in the connection, not all of them. Error appears quicker when running locally than on Kubernetes, but tends to disappear after a while and then come back.

Consumer Options:

```
{
    'bootstrap.servers': kafka_brokers_sasl,
    'sasl.mechanisms': 'PLAIN',
     'security.protocol': 'SASL_SSL',
     'sasl.username': 'token',
     'sasl.password': api_key,
     'log.connection.close' : False,
     'client.id': 'kafka-python-console-sample-consumer',
     'group.id': 'kafka-python-console-sample-consumer',
     'default.topic.config': {
         'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest'
      }
}
```

Error message:

```
%3|1539683094.048|FAIL|kafka-python-console-sample-consumer#consumer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://kafka02-prod01.messagehub.services.eu-de.bluemix.net]: sasl_ssl://kafka02-prod01.messagehub.services.eu-de.bluemix.net:9093/1: Failed to initializeSASL authentication: SASL Handshake not supported by broker (required by mechanism PLAIN) 
%3|1539683094.048|ERROR|kafka-python-console-sample-consumer#consumer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://kafka02-prod01.messagehub.services.eu-de.bluemix.net]: sasl_ssl://kafka02-prod01.messagehub.services.eu-de.bluemix.net:9093/1: Failed to initialize SASL authentication: SASL Handshake not supported by broker (required by mechanism PLAIN)
```

I have read multiple different posts but can't find a solution that works for me. How can I get rid of the message and make sure nothing is wrong with my broker connections?

Comment: Hint: `'sasl.mechanisms': 'PLAIN'` probably doesn't work well with `'security.protocol': 'SASL_SSL'`

Comment: @cricket_007 I followed this guide explaining how to use it with Kafka on IBM Cloud: https://github.com/ibm-messaging/event-streams-samples/blob/master/kafka-python-console-sample/app.py. How do you propose to use it, and which one to change?

Comment: I'm not particularly sure about the Confluent Python library. If you think you've ran into an error, though, perhaps you can report the issue here https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues